# Comment formuler « System Administrator Appreciation Day » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

Aujourd'hui est le [System Administrator Appreciation Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Administrator_Appreciation_Day). Nous voulons reconnaître notre collègue, mais nous n'avons aucune idée comment traduire cette journée en Français. Y a-t-il une meilleure traduction que *Journée d'appréciation des administrateurs sytème* ?

Comment: Je pense que vous voulez plutôt rendre honneur à votre collègue ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On pourrait également opter pour la concision en sous-entendant (comme c'est courant pour d'autres fêtes et événements du même type) le sens de *célébration*, et choisir de traduire **Jour des administrateurs (système)**.

Comment: +1, mais **Journée** (s) semble plus usité

Comment: @cl-r J'aime bien cette variante aussi, je trouve les deux satisfaisantes à vrai dire...

Answer (score 11):

Dans la même lignée que la Fête des [Mères](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte_des_m%C3%A8res), [Pères](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte_des_P%C3%A8res), [Grands-mères](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte_des_grands-m%C3%A8res), [Secrétaires](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte_des_secr%C3%A9taires), etc., pourquoi ne pas célébrer la **Fête des SysAdmin**?

Comment: Tant qu'à chercher un équivalent français, pourquoi utiliser Sys(tem)Admin(istrator)?

Comment: Parce que **Fête des Administrateurs Système** fait un peu longuet je trouve, et surtout parce, comme de nombreux termes en relation avec l'informatique, c'est souvent plus rapide et mieux compris d'utiliser le terme anglais.

Answer (score 1):

Nous n'avons pas vraiment ce genre de journées mais
*journée de célébration des administrateurs système* semble pas mal.